# BindException with INTERNET permission requested

Tags: java, android, sockets, bind

I have seen several questions regarding SocketException when using Android, but none of them cover the BindException that I get even with the INTERNET permission specified in my manifest.

Here is part of my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

Here is the relevant portion of my LogCat output:

```
04-22 14:49:06.117: DEBUG/MyLibrary(4844): Address to bind: 192.168.1.14 port: 843
04-22 14:49:06.197: WARN/System.err(4844): java.net.BindException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)
04-22 14:49:06.207: WARN/System.err(4844):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socketBindImpl(Native Method)
04-22 14:49:06.207: WARN/System.err(4844):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.bind(OSNetworkSystem.java:107)
04-22 14:49:06.217: WARN/System.err(4844):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:184)
04-22 14:49:06.217: WARN/System.err(4844):     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:414)
04-22 14:49:06.227: WARN/System.err(4844):     at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.ServerSocketChannelImpl$ServerSocketAdapter.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
04-22 14:49:06.227: WARN/System.err(4844):     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:367)
04-22 14:49:06.237: WARN/System.err(4844):     at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.ServerSocketChannelImpl$ServerSocketAdapter.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:283)
04-22 14:49:06.237: WARN/System.err(4844):     at mylibrary.net.PolicyConnection$PolicyServerWorker.(PolicyConnection.java:201)
```

I Really hope this is a simple problem and not something complicated by the fact that the binding is occurring within a worker thread on a port less than 1024.

**Update**

Looks as if this is a privileged port issue, anyone know how to bind to ports lower than 1024 in Android?

```
    SelectorProvider provider = SelectorProvider.provider();
    try {
        ServerSocketChannel channel = provider.openServerSocketChannel();
        policySocket = channel.socket();
        Log.d("MyLibrary", "Address to bind: " + device.getAddress().getAddress() + " port: 843");              
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(device.getAddress().getAddress()), 843);
        policySocket.bind(addr);
        policySocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        policySocket.setReceiveBufferSize(256);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> anyone know how to bind to ports lower
>   than 1024 in Android?

Either root your phone, modify the firmware, or don't bind to ports lower than 1024. That's a Linux thing more than an Android thing.

Comment: Hmmm...How to do this in a rooted environment. We build our own android platform for an embedded device. What permissions do I need to give to an android service to get privilege to bind on port 24?

Comment: @videoguy: There are no permissions. The process must run as root (or as a user account with admin privileges, perhaps).

Comment: unfortunately, but how resolve this situation. In my hardware they are using 1002? Thanks in advance

Comment: @sandeepmaaram: Presumably, the people who created the firmware for your hardware have a process running with root privileges that is using port 1002. If you have questions about that, start by talking to the hardware manufacturer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I Signed my app with `signapk.jar` and put my app inside `system/priv-app` and grant all 755 permissions to it. but still can not play streams with ports lower than 1024!

Comment: @MHSFisher: AFAIK, that just makes your app be pre-installed. It does not grant your app root permissions (again, AFAIK).

Answer (score -2):

Try add permission android.permission.INTERNET 

it worked for me