# java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied) while using sockets

Tags: android, sockets, port, ip-address, serversocket

I have a weight machine which is connected to a wifi network. My phone is also connected to same wifi network. I want to get weight from that weight machine using internet address and port number but I am getting BindException.

I have added all permissions in manifest. Those are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Code :

```
class MyServer implements Runnable {

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
    String message;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetSocketAddress tcp = new InetSocketAddress("192.1.9.0", 2);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(tcp);

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                message = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                Log.e("TAG", "run:message " + message);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

error log : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDXAr.jpg

Please help what is wrong with it.

Comment: Please provide error log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - [Either root your phone, modify the firmware, or don't bind to ports lower than 1024](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2695160/12396017)